# Error while implementing calendar from primeng in angular

Tags: html, node.js, angular

I am trying to use calender of primeng in angular v4 to display time and date. I have aforementioned the places where i define the module,html where i have defined the calendar, package.json and error. Please let me know if any more thing needs to be mentioned to clear the error.

I have defined it in

**master-system.module.ts**

```
import { CalendarModule } from 'primeng/components/calendar/calendar'

@NgModule({
 CalendarModule,

  ],
 declarations: [], 
 providers:[ToasterService]

 })
```

**transaction.component.ts**

```
import { CalendarModule } from 'primeng/components/calendar/calendar'
```

And used in

**transaction.component.html**

```
   <div class="ui-g-12 ui-md-4">
                  <h3>Time</h3>
                  <p-calendar [(ngModel)]="date7" [showTime]="true"> 
   </p-calendar> {{date7}}
              </div>
```

**package.json**

```
 {
 "name": "cateina-tech",
 "version": "1.0.0-alpha.6",
 "description": "Open Source Bootstrap Admin Template",
 "author": "",
  "url": "http://cateina.com",
  "scripts": {
  "ng": "ng",
  "start": "ng serve",
  "build": "ng build",
  "test": "ng test",
  "lint": "ng lint",
  "e2e": "ng e2e"
 },
"private": true,
"dependencies": {
"@angular/common": "4.3.4",
"@angular/compiler": "4.3.4",
"@angular/core": "4.3.4",
"@angular/forms": "4.3.4",
"@angular/http": "4.3.4",
"@angular/platform-browser": "4.3.4",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.3.4",
"@angular/router": "4.3.4",
"@angular/upgrade": "4.3.4",
"angular-2-local-storage": "^1.0.1",
"angular-localstorage": "^1.1.5",
"body-parser": "^1.18.2",
"chart.js": "2.6.0",
"core-js": "2.5.0",
"cors": "^2.8.4",
"date-time": "^2.1.0",
"express": "^4.16.2",
"express-jwt": "^5.3.1",
"express-session": "^1.15.6",
"font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
"jquery": "^3.3.1",
"jsonwebtoken": "^8.2.0",
"jwt-decode": "^2.2.0",
"localstorage": "^0.1.0",
"moment": "2.18.1",
"mysql": "^2.15.0",
"mysql-server": "^1.0.5",
"ng2-charts": "1.6.0",
"ng2-order-pipe": "^0.1.5",
"ng2-search-filter": "^0.4.7",
"ngx-bootstrap": "1.8.1",
"ngx-ellipsis": "^1.0.7",
"ngx-gauge": "^1.0.0-beta.2",
"ngx-loading": "^1.0.14",
"ngx-pagination": "^3.1.0",
"node-datetime": "^2.0.6",
"nodemailer": "^4.6.3",
"nodemon": "^1.17.3",
"path": "*",
"pepipost-sdk-nodejs": "^0.4.0",
"primeng": "^5.2.4",
"q": "^1.5.1",
"request": "^2.83.0",
"request-promise": "^4.2.2",
"restify": "^6.3.4",
"rootpath": "^0.1.2",
"rxjs": "5.4.3",
"save": "^2.3.2",
"ts-helpers": "1.1.2",
"zone.js": "0.8.16"
},
"devDependencies": {
"@angular/cli": "^1.7.3",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "4.3.4",
"@types/jasmine": "2.5.53",
"@types/node": "8.0.20",
"codelyzer": "3.1.2",
"jasmine-core": "2.7.0",
"jasmine-spec-reporter": "4.2.0",
"karma": "1.7.0",
"karma-chrome-launcher": "2.2.0",
"karma-cli": "1.0.1",
"karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "1.3.0",
"karma-jasmine": "1.1.0",
"karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "0.2.2",
"protractor": "5.1.2",
"ts-node": "3.3.0",
"tslint": "5.6.0",
"typescript": "^2.3.4"
 },
 "engines": {
  "node": ">= 6.9.0",
  "npm": ">= 3.0.0"
 }
 }
```

**Error in angular terminal**

> ERROR in Error: Metadata version mismatch for module
>   /home/dell/Downloads/Adaani5.0.0/node_modules/primeng/components/calendar/calendar.d.ts,found
>   version 4, expected 3, resolving symbol MasterSystemModule in
>   /home/dell/Downloads/Adaani5.0.0/src/app/master-system/master-system.module.ts,
>   resolving symbol MasterSystemModule in
>   /home/dell/Downloads/Adaani5.0.0/src/app/master-system/master-system.module.ts
>       at syntaxError (/home/dell/Downloads/Adaani5.0.0/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:1725:34)
>       at simplifyInContext (/home/dell/Downloads/Adaani5.0.0/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:24949:23)
>       at StaticReflector.simplify (/home/dell/Downloads/Adaani5.0.0/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:24961:13)
>       at StaticReflector.annotations (/home/dell/Downloads/Adaani5.0.0/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:24391:41)
>       at _getNgModuleMetadata (/home/dell/Downloads/Adaani5.0.0/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/src/ngtools_impl.js:138:31)
>       at _extractLazyRoutesFromStaticModule (/home/dell/Downloads/Adaani5.0.0/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/src/ngtools_impl.js:109:26)
>       at includeLazyRouteAndSubRoutes (/home/dell/Downloads/Adaani5.0.0/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/src/ngtools_impl.js:66:25)
>       at Array.reduce ()
>       at Object.listLazyRoutesOfModule (/home/dell/Downloads/Adaani5.0.0/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/src/ngtools_impl.js:54:36)
>       at Function.NgTools_InternalApi_NG_2.listLazyRoutes (/home/dell/Downloads/Adaani5.0.0/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/src/ngtools_api.js:91:39)
>       at AotPlugin._getLazyRoutesFromNgtools (/home/dell/Downloads/Adaani5.0.0/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/plugin.js:240:66)
>       at _donePromise.Promise.resolve.then.then.then.then.then (/home/dell/Downloads/Adaani5.0.0/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/plugin.js:493:24)
>       at 
>       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)

Comment: most of the chances are there for version mismatch

Comment: what needs to be done for that

Comment: Please check the valid version of primeng with that version of angular

Comment: i have mentioned the package.json which has the versions. Does anything more is required for checking. Please check and let me know ..i alone am not capable to do tht

Comment: Update all of your packages to make them match. When you run `npm install` you should see no errors, no warnings. Try using the last versions of the packages, and if you don't, be sure to fix the versions (`~2.0.0` or `^2.0.0` should be `2.0.0`)

Comment: my npm version when i do --> npm -v  is --> 5.8.0 . Is it  improper

Comment: for angular 4 you need  node 6.9.x and npm 3.x.x

Comment: it has node -v -->
v8.9.3  and npm -v -->5.8.0

Comment: still getting the error

Comment: @SuchetaShrivastava can you create a stackblitz to reproduce

Comment: please refer this link
https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/8229

Answer (score 0):

my take is the following:

1. delete node_modules folder
2. run `npm upgrade` and `npm update`
3. if the problem still exists, try the steps 1-2 again, but this time with `-g` flag

+1: if you get any warnings about "update available", then do it what is described in the message